# How to make blur in Inkscape

Tags: vector, svg, blur, inkscape

I am learning Inkscape and vector graphics in general. 
What I am trying to draw is a simple person for my adventure game. This is what I have done:
 * basic contours - no problems, path editing is quite intuitive in Inkscape,
 * basic colors - I was little bit suprised, that I cannot simple fill the areas, but I get it now.

The main problems are the shadows and the highlights. 
How can I get such smooth shading like in http://www.scalablegfx.com/svg/girl-sitting-on-floor? 
Is there some way to make the gaussian blur, or something similar? Is there some menu item I have missed?

I have tried to simulate it by gradients, but the effect is not what I want to achieve. Even when I make several layers of gradients, it is not the same.

Thx in advance,
Sylvia

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 7):

With any object, you can go to the 'Fill and Stroke' panel and modify the 'Blur' parameter. It's just over the 'Opacity'. It blurs all the object with a gaussian function.

I'm using 0.91.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for "feather". Try:

**Filters > ABCs > Feather.**